# Change index of lof from 1 to Fig. 1

Tags: table-of-contents, floats, koma-script

So I want to change the index in the lof from 1 to Fig. 1:

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}

\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{chngcntr}
\counterwithout{figure}{chapter}

\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}
    \begin{figure}
        \centering
        \includegraphics[height=0.3\textheight]{example-image}
        \caption[Example Caption]{Example Caption}
        \label{fig:Example}
    \end{figure}

    \listoffigures

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add option `listof=entryprefix` and redefine `\listoflofentryname`:

```
\documentclass[
  listof=entryprefix
]{scrreprt}

%\usepackage{float}% do you need this package?
\usepackage{chngcntr}
\counterwithout{figure}{chapter}
\renewcommand*\listoflofentryname{Fig.}

\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}
    \begin{figure}
        \centering
        \includegraphics[height=0.3\textheight]{example-image}
        \caption[Example Caption]{Example Caption}
        \label{fig:Example}
    \end{figure}

    \listoffigures
\end{document}
```

Result:

[image]

Or with a KOMA-Script class and package `babel`:

```
\documentclass[
  listof=entryprefix,
  english
]{scrreprt}
\usepackage{babel}

%\usepackage{float}% do you need this package?
\usepackage{chngcntr}
\counterwithout{figure}{chapter}
\newcaptionname{english}{\listoflofentryname}{Fig.}

\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}
    \begin{figure}
        \centering
        \includegraphics[height=0.3\textheight]{example-image}
        \caption[Example Caption]{Example Caption}
        \label{fig:Example}
    \end{figure}

    \listoffigures
\end{document}
```